# Android: error while installing v7 appcompat (app compat library)

Tags: android, eclipse

I cannot install app compat v7 library. I am following the instructions given at https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Strangely,  instructions from above link used to work on my old system. I open SDK manager, select Android Support Library, accept licence and install. But I get the following error.

Any suggestions appreciated (I spent several hours trying to figure this out)

```
       Downloading Android Support Library, revision 20
       Download interrupted: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:5050 refused
       Done. Nothing was installed.
```

***EDIT***

@SilentKnight @alijandro @Anggrayudi H

I restarted the system. Turned off windows firewall (I donot have anti-virus). Started the SDKManager and tried installing. Again the same problem. Reviewing SDKManager log, I see following error messages (which came up when SDK Manager was started). I manually open all these error links on the web and I do see those files. However SDK Manager is not fetching them when it is first started and hence cannot install the app compat. Any idea on why SDKManager is able to fetch some files but not some other

```
           Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:5050 refused
         Fetched Add-ons List successfully
         Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml

        Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: HttpHostConnect Connection to http://127.0.0.1:5050 refused
         Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml

          Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml, reason: HttpHostConnect Connection to http://127.0.0.1:5050 refused
           Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml

          Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml/addon.xml, reason: HttpHostConnect Connection to http://127.0.0.1:5050 refused

         Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml

       Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml, reason: HttpHostConnect Connection to http://127.0.0.1:5050 refused

         Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml

         Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml, reason: HttpHostConnect Connection to http://127.0.0.1:5050 refused
```

Comment: Did you have the proxy setting in you Android SDK Manager? But the proxy is unreachable, refuse connection.

Comment: Have you tried to turn off the Firewall on PC or on antivirus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Android SDK Manager setting menu, `Tool` -> `Options` -> `Proxy Settings`, make sure `HTTP Proxy Server` and `HTTP Proxy Port` are empty.

Then in you SDK Manager setting menu, `Packages` -> `Reload`. It will fresh and update the data again for you.

Comment: worked. I have to turn off the windows-antivirus during the above steps-thans